# Map function returning whole array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, array.prototype.map

```
const flight = () => {

return (
    <div className="tour-list-area">
      {hotelFlightPackageListTest.map((flightDetails) => {
        return <FlightHotelPackageItem key={flightDetails.outbounddate} {...flightDetails} />
      })};
    </div>

  )
  };
```

Inside`<FlightHotelPackageItem>` I am logging it like so:

```
const FlightHotelPackageItem = (flightDetails) => {
console.log(flightDetails)
```

The returned result is the entire array as though I just passed in the whole array. I imagine it's some dumb syntax error, would appreciate someone pointing out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `map` returns something for each item.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: The issue is that the entire array is being passed into`<FlightHotelPackageItem` instead of just a single item from that array each time. I want it to be looping through each object in the array.

Comment: I created a sandbox and your code works as expacted:

https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-cdn-j8xzbg?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Do you see each object in the array in the console as separate logs? Because that is what your code is doing currently.

Comment: Nope it's coming through as the same array. Really weird how it works in the sandbox and not in my project. Any ideas what could cause this? EDIT: If I go into <FlightHotelPackageItem> and change each instance to flightDetails[0].whatever it will work but obviously thats not the solution as i want to list all the objects not just the first one.

Comment: I just had an idea that might work but I'm struggling with the syntax. Maybe using a fori loop for the array? How would that look syntax wise though?

Comment: maybe you're passing whole array into `<Flight...>` component. check the spell. `items.map((item)⇒ <Flight {...items}>)` like this.